# Where can I config service startup options in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kvm, init

I'm not used to using Ubuntu or Debian as a server. I'm more accustomed to Red Hat/Fedora ways and even Gentoo (yikes).

Under Red Hat installs, you can often configure most services that start from init using config files in /etc/sysconfig named by the service.  Is there and equivalent thing under Ubuntu?

Specifically I'm trying to control how the libvirtd and kvm processes are started as far as command line options go. I need to add the --listen option somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu and Debian use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) as a replacement for `init`, but legacy `init` scripts are supported. Chances are that you can add the option in a script in `/etc/init.d` with the same name as the service. Also look in `/etc/init` for `.conf` files that control the runlevels that services are started and stopped on and how they're respawned, etc.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. The place I needed to set the --listen option was in /etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf.

Answer (score 7):

First find your config you want to change using the following command:

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Then change the specific config using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full rocketchat.service
```